# How to properly encapsulate classes and constants in dart(flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

My scenario is this:

I have currently the following folder&files structure

```
lib/pages/home_page/
       home_page.dart
       constants.dart
```

I had previously only a huge single file home_page.dart and the goal now is to split that and have clean code while still encapsulating the stuff only under the home_page domain

I have a couple of constants in constants.dart that want to be used only in home_page.dart like for example `const CACHE_KEY='blabla'; //etc`

**What I tried**
I used `part` and `part of
syntax and it works fine for the mentioned question, BUT it does not feel scalable and right.

I want to have also private classes under the /home_page/ folder that I want to be accessed only by home_page.dart and nothing else.

What is the best practice to achieve this ?

Comment: You're almost there.  Make an enum class that is library local (begins with underscore) and use part/partof to manage that across multiple files.

Comment: what about private normal classes ? For example `class _Detail` and re-use it across my folder/lib only